# is there a better way to render a set of 50+ svg icons in another component without using the exact path of files with the svg extension

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

[image]im so exhausting of trying to get the functionality of the exact design attached in this Picture, I do not know how to import/render these reusable SVG icons shown in the second picture without having to import every single icon path from local files !

please any kind of help or support will be highly appreciated

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Icon({ name, ...otherProps }) {
  /* Use state hook to store icon module value */
  const [iconModule, setIconModule] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    /* Use dynamic import to get corresponding icon as a module */
    import(`./icons/${name}.svg`)
      .then((module) => {
        /* Persist data in state */
        setIconModule(module);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        /* Do not forget to handle errors */
        console.error(`Icon with name: ${name} not found!`);
      });
  }, [name /* update on name change */]);

  const renderIcon = () => {
    if (!iconModule) return null;

    /**
     * Equal to:
     * import { ReactComponent as Icon } from "./path/to/icon.svg";
     */
    const Component = iconModule.ReactComponent;

    return <Component {...otherProps} />;
  };

  return <>{renderIcon()}</>;
}

export default Icon;
```

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, `svg` is also a DOM element. So `<svg />` can be exported from a valid component.

```
import createSvgIcon from './createSvgIcon'

const BackArrowIcon = createSvgIcon(
  <g transform="translate(-12.75 -99.75)">
    <path transform="translate(13 100)" />
  </g>
)

export default BackArrowIcon
```

Just an idea, which is similar to yours.

```
import { memo } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const size = '24px'
const stroke = (props: any) => props.stroke || '#bbb'
const fill = (props: any) => props.fill || 'none'
const strokeWidth = '0.5px'

const IconStyle = styled.svg`
  width: ${size};
  height: ${size};
  fill: ${fill};
  stroke: ${stroke};
  stroke-width: ${strokeWidth};
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
`

function createSvgIcon(path: any) {
  return memo((props: SvgIconProps) => (
    <IconStyle {...props}>
      {path}
    </IconStyle>
  ))
}

export default createSvgIcon
```

The major difference is that i didn't use dynamic import, so svg file isn't a resources, instead it becomes part of a component of React.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, however sadly this solution doesn’t work with my case .In fact I managed to import one or two of the icons from ( iconSet) component into another component, but there’s nothing showing at all .Will you please write me a more clear code snippet that I can understand and easily capable of refactoring/reused!

Comment: I basically just want to show you that you can use `<svg />` directly in your code, instead of `import` a physical svg file. But you still need to experiment how to integrate with your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [SVG sprite](https://svgsprit.es/) it make use of sprite file, so you won't be referencing the path over and over agian.

[For more details on sprite file](https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/)